# Coldfusion 8 - mapping conflict causes "argument is not of interface type" error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have been researching this, and cannot seem to find anything about it.

We work on CF8. When my coworker tried installing my latest code updates, he started seeing errors that the argument supplied to a function was not of the specified interface type. Worked fine for me. Same set up. Sometimes it works for him. Also have the problem on our dev server.

I have since been able to isolate and reproduce the problem locally.

Here is the set up.

I have 2 mappings on the server:

- "webapp/" goes to c:\webroot\
- "packages/" goes to c:\webroot\[domain]

Then I created an interface, call it ISubject and a component that implements it, called Person, and saved both under packages. Here is the declaration for Person:

```
cfcomponent implements="packages.ISubject"
```

Finally, there is a component, called SubjectMediator with a function, called setSubject, that wants an object of the ISubject interface type. Here is the argument declaration for setSubject:

```
cfargument name="subject_object" type="packages.ISubject"
```

To implement:

```
variables.person = createObject("component", "packages.Person").Init();  
variables.subjectMediator = createObject("component", "packages.SubjectMediator ").Init();  
variables.subjectMediator.setSubject(variables.person);
```

That last line throws the error that Person is not of type ISubject. If I do isInstanceOf() on Person against ISubject it validates fine.

So the reason this is happening? Dumping getMetaData(variables.person) shows me that the interface path is webapp.[domain].ISubject. And indeed, if I change the type attribute of the argument to use this path instead of packages.ISubject, all is fine again.

Coldfusion seems to be arbitrarily choosing which mapping to resolve the interface to, and then simply doing a string comparison for check the type argument?

Anyone had to contend with this? I need the webapp mapping, and I cannot change all references to "packages" to "webapp.[domain]." I also am not able in this instance to use an application-specific mapping for webapp. While any of these 3 options would circumvent the issue, I'm hoping someone has some insight...

The best I've got is to set argument type to "any" and then check isInstanceOf() inside the function... Seems like poor form.

Thanks,

Jen

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the contents of the packages mapping to outside the webroot? This seems like the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wish... Unfortunately, our infrastructure guy won't let that happen.